# Calculating best memory allocation for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I am having lots of OutOfMemory exceptions with GeoServer 2.6.0, and now I'm trying to increase the memory allocated to it and Tomcat. How can I figure out the best allocation of memory to set in the configuration?

This is a virtual machine with 16Gb of RAM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ciao,
generally speaking I would give GeoServer an amount of heap memory between 1GB and 8GB.
It is rather difficult that it will use more than that.

It would actually be great if yoy could say more about what kind of data you are serving with GeoServer and which kind of requests you are usually sending to it. A stack trace might help as well.

Generally speaking there is a ton of documentation aroud on how to best tune GeoServer that it is worth reading. Some links below:

1. [GeoServer on Steroids](http://goo.gl/74XUPq)
2. [GeoServer in production](http://boundlessgeo.com/whitepaper/geoserver-production-2/)

Comment: As of now, serving a big bunch of GeoTIFFs as a large ImageMosaic. It's going to be publically accessible, though. At least in the beginning that server is also going to run Apache and a few Django web apps, so I suppose I have to avoid allocating the lot to GeoServer.

Comment: I'd better add that the big bunch of GeoTIFFs is about 400Gb large.

Comment: I am assuming you are mostly doing WMS GetMap against these mosaics.

That said, you'd need to check a few things:
-1- enable resource consumption limits on WMS as per this page http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/parameters.html
-2- use control flow to limit throughput of requests, see http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/controlflow.html for a starter
-3- configure properly the ImageMosaic in terms of parameter used at reading: see http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/raster_data/mosaic_pyramid.html

Comment: If this still does not help, please, move the discussion to the ML and provide a stacktrace and a heapdump as per this page: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/troubleshooting.html#using-jdk-tools-to-get-stack-and-memory-dumps

Comment: I will certainly look into that, but at the moment the server is not yet visible to the outside world and there is no other users than me, submitting one request only.